# Point application to non-embedded JRE after installation

Tags: java, install4j, cytoscape

Is there a way to point the application to a different JRE after installation? The application installed and created a i4j_jres folder for its embedded java. does this program allow for it to have a different java location without needing to specify an environment variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the contents of the file `.install4j\pref_jre.cfg` to use another JRE. It will still be checked if it matches the version requirements.

A programmatic way to do this with the install4j API is to call

```
com.install4j.api.JVMSelector.setPreferredJVM(...)
```